# Live tracking of an object in 3D space

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm not new but I'm already a beginner.
I'm posting a new question because I was wondering if there is a method to live-track the position of an object in tridimensional space.

I would like to use an RGB camera as input, the camera should film an object with some marker (QR or other types) and I would like to obtain on blender the live position in 3D space of the object.

Does someone know if there is any possibility of doing it?
Thank you in advance, Have a good day,
FG